# Compatibility between iPhone/iPad and Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I'm about to start a new app project for iPhone/iPad and I'm checking if there's any relevant issue between iphone and Phonegap compatibility?

The project most possible trouble will be the audio and video streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A look through the [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/) should tell you if the features you want are supported or not.